# Failed to create Javascript analog of Java method for password hashing using SHA-256 and salt

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, salt, pbkdf2

I've been strugling for a while now by trying to complete next goal : 
I have a "Reset password" page that supposed to send new password to the server. I would like to hash it with salt, so I could save it in DB eventually. On Server side I have next methods that creates password hash :

```java
public static String makeHash(String password, String salt) {
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        byte byteData[] = md.digest(makeHash(salt.toLowerCase()));

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteData);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        log.error("Unable to make hash for pass. No hashing.", e);
    }

    return password;
}

private static byte[] makeHash(String val) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(val.getBytes("UTF-8"));
}
```

I tried several Javascript libraries - crypto, crypto-js, SJCL , but couldn't manage to create same password as Java methods generates. For example, last working try out was :

```js
var crypto = require('crypto');
crypto.pbkdf2('123', 'test@gmail.com', 1000, 60, 'sha256', function(err, key) {
  if (err)
    throw err;
  console.log(key.toString('Base64'));  // 'c5e478d...1469e50'
});
```

And it generated me this hash - `Qr2lzotlRWj7BeJeFooMRj64auMPTb3PRhwLmfNcl4DCVAlFFibgOqZiyExZNO5i/icAUYoMjy73jSTd`, while Java gives me - `/pyQf3JCj5XoczfsYJ4LUb+y0DONGMl/AFzLiBTo8LA=`.

I cannot change backend, since it running already for some time, so I was hoping that maybe someone could help me out with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the same algorithm on both sides. In Java you're using simply SHA-256 and in node you're using PBKDF2 with SHA-256.

Node.js' crypto module provides the [`createHash(algorithm)`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhash_algorithm) function. Where you can specify SHA-256 directly. PBKDF2 is an algorithm that only uses different hashing functions under the hood.

If you want hash passwords, then it is much safer to use PBKDF2 with a lot of iterations (> 86,000) and a random salt that you store alongside the password hash.

Java has support for PBKDF2 in its standard library.

If you really want to use SHA-256 directly and I *strongly advise against it*, you can use the following code:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var key = "123";
var salt = "test@gmail.com";

key = crypto.createHash('sha256')
        .update(key, "utf8")
        .update(makeHash(salt))
        .digest("base64");

console.log(key);

function makeHash(val) {
    return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(val, "utf8").digest();
}
```

Output:

```
/pyQf3JCj5XoczfsYJ4LUb+y0DONGMl/AFzLiBTo8LA=
```

Note that `Hash.digest()` takes an optional output encoding and not additional data.

Comment: I tried to create hash with SHA-256 algorithm like this - https://gist.github.com/azakordonets/e436ccbdb2a4aedac52a and try to imitate Java approach, but i failed. As a result i was getting `JUE2ZSVBNFklMjBCLyU5REElN0VIZyVFRiVEQ08lQjglQTBKJTFGJTNGJUZGJTFGJUEwJTdFJTk5JThFJTg2JUY3JUY3JUEyeiVFMw==`

Comment: Added full code example, but I strongly advise against using SHA-256 directly for hashing passwords.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed one littel thing and was so close - you saved a lot of my time :)